# Graphics Magick installation on Mac El Capitan 10.11.3 for TYPO3

Tags: macos, installation, typo3, graphicsmagick

I'm frustrated. I'm a total beginner in this (TYPO3), know well about HTML/CSS though but all the info I found on the web reads like Chinese for me. Like that one: http://mac-dev-env.patrickbougie.com/graphicsmagick/

I have no clue what that means!

I've downloaded GM, extracted the zip and double-clicked the configure file. The installation finished without any problems (as far as I can tell).

So here's the ting: can anybody please tell me, how this sort of installation is suppossed to be completed? I need it from the very beginning, actually from unpacking the zip.

Do I have to have another program, like this terminal program on the Mac, where you have to type in command lines? Do I have to write or edit code somewhere? Do I need to create folders? Where, in the TYPO3-Backend, can I check if it even works?

TYPO3 is installed and it works perfectly so far. THANKS A LOT! :)

PS: I really like to learn this (!), but my head is bumping right now :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Easy way:**

If you want to "just install" GM I suggest you to use one of OS X package managers like [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) or [macports](https://www.macports.org/). They can simplify configuration, building and installation process for you. So you'll only need to open Terminal and type (depending on chosen package manager):

`brew install graphicsmagick` or `port install graphicsmagick`

To verify that your installation is successful open Terminal and type `gm version`, as result you should see version and other details of your installation.

**Fundamental way:**

If you want learn how to build and install GM from sources, I recommend you to start reading [official documentation](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/INSTALL-unix.html). And then, by the way, read about "Make" and other tools used in build process.

Comment: Simply installing `graphicsmagick` didn't solve the problem for me. The issue is that `gm` does not point to any binary. What I did is add the following in my ~/.bash_profile: `alias gm='/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.8-12/bin/magick'`

Answer (score 0):

As **@Oles Savluk** pointed easiest way to install such stuff is using homebrew. When you'll install it already, open **new** terminal window and use command `which gm` to find the path it will be i.e.: `/usr/local/bin/gm` - copy/write it and use in the TYPO3's Install Tool in proper place.

Comment: Thank you as well, biesior. I tried out some things and it works now. All the best for you!